# Postgres database, Error : NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to do a Docker image but I have some problems. Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
      - 35729:35729
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASS=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

And there my Dockerfile :

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/web

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install nodejs
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
# copy project
COPY . .

RUN python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
RUN python -m pip install Pillow
# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install Pillow

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Anf finally my entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

When I do that :

`docker-compose up -d --build`

It works perfectly. Then I type that :

`docker-compose exec web npm start --prefix ./front/`

It looks ok but when I type in my browser `http://localhost:3000/`

I got that kind of messages : `Error : NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

I thought the front is ok but I am not able to communicate with the back and so the database.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you confirm that the Django server is up and running inside?

Comment: I think Django is not running when I try localhost:8000 I am not able to reach my local server

Comment: Your command to start Django is likely not being run, because of the entrypoint in your Dockerfile. Try removing the entrypoint, rebuild, and check if the Django server starts up.

Answer (score -1):

As I can see in docker-compose.yml file you did not define the environment variables for Postgres in the web container. Please define the environment variables for the below :

**DATABASE**

**SQL_HOST**

**SQL_PORT**

Then bring down the docker and bring up the docker hopefully it will help you.